# Template struct to use uint8_t or uint16_t depending on configuration: "identifier " " is undefined"

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am trying to create a template struct for a configurable device that can be made to output either 8 or 16 bit data. To avoid creating two copies of a struct with one handling `uint8_t` and the other `uint16_t, I am trying to create a template struct that can handle whatever datatype is passed through.

My structs are as follows in my header file:

```c++
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

template <typename T>
typedef struct {
    size_t      aa;
    uint16_t    bb;
    T          cc[4568]; // can be uint8_t or uint16_t depending on config
} raw_data_t;

template <typename T>
typedef struct {
    uint64_t            timestamp;
    size_t              a;
    float               b;
    float               c;  
    uint16_t            d;
    size_t              e;
    float               f;
    float               g;
    raw_data_t<T>       h;
} raw_data_status_t;

#pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

I want to be able to pass the data type in with something like this:

```c++
raw_data_status_t<uint16_t> raw_data_status;

raw_data_status.raw_data<T>.cc[0] = 123;
raw_data_status.raw_data.aa = sizeof(int);
```

However I receive a bunch of `identifier raw_data_status_t is undefined` and `template decleration of typedef` error messages on compile.

Comment: The name of `raw_data_status`'s member of type `raw_data<T>` is `h`, not `raw_data<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

you ignore some complains from the compiler
in main function it should be:

```
raw_data_status_t<uint16_t> raw_data_status;

raw_data_status.h.cc[0] = 123;
raw_data_status.h.aa = sizeof(int);
```

tested at https://godbolt.org/z/obsvesc8G